# Core/Uncore voltage on Android device with adb

Tags: performance, adb, cpu

There is a way to get core and/or uncore voltage from Android device with adb on Linux terminal?

Comment: There is no standard way. There are too many `PMIC` options available.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer.
To view current core voltage:

```
shell@msm8994:/ # cat /sys/class/regulator/regulator.3/microvolts              
785000
```